# Deleting all files created by script after finsihing script php

Tags: php, xml, delete-file

Is there a way to delete all files created by running the script. I have written a code were a lot of xml files are created. They have to be stored till the script run through all the xml files. These files aren't necessary any more when the script is finished. Is there a possibility to write a code that will delete these files in the same script?

I used unlike(filname) in my loop by saving the xml files locally. The problem is that it removed my file before I could used in the next part of my code.

```
foreach ($links as $lin){
unlike($filename);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything for this? If so, please share with a minimal, complete and verifiable example, with errors and behaviours, otherwise, we cannot help as we are not here to give you code, rather to help you fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add on the end of script-file a code like this:

```
$files = glob('path/to/files/dir/*');
foreach($files as $file){
  if(is_file($file)) {
    unlink($file); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got errors because the directory contained also other files. With the is_file it works.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following script

```
$files = glob('path/to/temp/*'); // get all file names
 foreach($files as $file){ // iterate files
  if(is_file($file))
    unlink($file); // delete file
 }
```

If you want to remove 'hidden' files like .htaccess, you have to use

```
$files = glob('path/to/temp/{,.}*', GLOB_BRACE);
```